# Application of Maximum modulus theorem on unbounded region

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come accross a situation of an analytic function outside a closed circular region $|z|=R$ having its expression at $z=\infty$ as 
$f(z)=a_0+a_1/z+a_2/z^2+\cdots $ with $a_0\neq 0$. Can I say maximum is attained on $|z|=R$ if $f$ is continuous on $|z|=R$  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and  the proof is easy. Define $g(z)=f(\frac 1 z)$ for  $0<|z| \leq \frac  1 R$. Note that $f(z) \to a_0 $ as $z \to \infty$. Hence $g(z)\to a_0$ as $z \to 0$. So $g$ extends to an analytic function in $|z| \leq \frac 1  R$. Apply MMP to  this function.

Comment: Thank you very much.